# Stuck with moving Elements in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a button to move my last image element in front of my first image element so I used the append function but when I click on the moveUpButton all it does is shift my elements left till none are showing. Am I missing something in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
.wrappedElement {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: cyan;
}
img.wrappedElement {
    border-color: brown;
    border-width: 4px;
}
div.wrappedElement {
    padding: 5;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#hideButton").click(function (){$("img").hide();});
    $("#showButton").click(function (){$("img").show();});
    $("#toggleButton").click(function (){$("img").toggle();});
    $("#evenButton").click(function (){$("img:odd").hide();        

            $("img:even").show();});
    $("#oddButton").click(function (){$("img:even").hide();         
            $("img:odd").show();}); 
    $("#moveUpButton").click(function 
            (){$("img:first").append($("img:last"));});
    $("#moveDownButton").click(function 
            (){$("img:last").prepend($("img:first"));});
    });
</script>

<script language="javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("img").addClass("wrappedElement");
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="buttonBar">
    <button id="hideButton" type="submit">Hide</button>
    <button id="showButton" type="submit">Show</button>
    <button id="toggleButton" type="submit">Toggle</button>
    <button id="evenButton" type="submit">Show Even Images</button>
    <button id="oddButton" type="submit">Show Odd Images</button>
    <button id="moveUpButton" stype="submit">Move images left</button>
    <button id="moveDownButton" stype="submit">Move images right</button>
<p>
<div id="content">
    <img src="Forest Flowers.jpg" id="forest" title="Forest Flowers"/>
        <img src="Frangipani Flowers.jpg" id="frangipani" title="Frangipani 
Flowers"/>
    <img src="Garden.jpg" id="garden" title="Garden"/>
    <img src="Green Sea Turtle.jpg" id="turtle" title="Green Sea Turtle"/>
    <img src="Humpback Whale.jpg" id="whale" title="Humpback Whale"/>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You included jQuery twice. `$(function(){` is equivalent to `$("document").ready(`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the double jquery import

```
<script language="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="_scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

You should use only one of them.

UPDATE:

Next, you should change the moveUpButton and moveDownButton to insert properly:

```
$("#moveUpButton").click(function 
            (){$("img:first").parent().append($("img:last"));});
$("#moveDownButton").click(function 
            (){$("img:last").parent().prepend($("img:first"));});
});
```

You need to insert in the parent of the target image (the div).

Comment: Worked perfect, I didnt even think about the parent. Thanks much.